# Can I install a micro-SD card into my Note 2 after I've enabled device encryption?

Tags: encryption, external-sd

I recently got a Note 2 and enabled device encryption. I want to put a micro-SD in it now to expand my storage capacity, but when I go to settings, it won't let me mount the card. Is it because of the device encryption? Is there a way to add this drive without decrypting and re-encrypting?

Comment: A good question! It's possible (technically). Do a backup of your old data first! You might succeed to re-format the **new** sd-card using your Note2. If that doesn't work, the only way I can think of is rather hackish and involves some basic Linux skills: Raw-copy over all the encrypted data from the old SD card to the new one and try accessing it (it should have the old size still), if you can **then** reformat it, it might grow to the new size. If you succeeded, restore the data to the new crypted SD card. PS: I'm curious if it works, let me know! If this is to vague just ask or chat

Comment: ce4's approach sounds good. You might want to contact Samsung too.